# Применение асинхронного программирования.

Tags: асинхронность, события

Где может использоваться асинхронное программирование?

Вопрос даже скорее не в том, где оно используется сегодня, а где оно используется и могло бы использоваться. Какого рода задачи удобно решать в асинхронном стиле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно это работа с IO, а именно сеть и (довольно часто) файлы. В первом случае необходимость асинхронной работы с сокетами очевидна: передача датаграмм бывает медленной, etc; в случае работы с файловой системой используется почти в тех же самых целях оптимизации.

Рекомендую почитать об этом [в MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228969.aspx): там .Net, но о таких вещах сложно читать в отрыве от конкретной платформы. Цитата о вариантах использования:

- Выполнять затратные по времени задачи, такие как загрузки и операции с базами данных "в фоновом режиме", не прерывая работу приложения.
- Запускать одновременно несколько операций, получая уведомление о завершении каждой из них.
- Ожидать доступность ресурсов без остановки ("зависания") приложения.

Возможно будет интересным почитать о CPS и async/await из C# в .net 4.0 [у Эрика Липперта](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/archive/tags/continuation+passing+style/). Их предназначение - сделать решение асинхронных задач действительно *удобным*.

Comment: Как ни странно, типичный GUI клиент-сервер можно (и нужно) рассматривать именно как асинхронную программу.

Вообще, если мы выдаем какой-либо запрос, а до получения результата к нам поступают данные из независимого источника, то часто удобнее использовать асинхронную модель, а не набор потоков.

Еще один пример, ядра ОС.

Comment: Это зависит от реализации. Никто не мешает сделать ожидание ответа от сервера синхронным, однако это действительно плохая практика.

Comment: Сервер на асинхронных сокетах очень производительный например